# Display backend data in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to display backend data in the front with react, i did recieve the data because when i inspect the response in the Network tab in the console i found them,
now to display this data on the interface i am calling the loadData() function in componentDidMount :

```
 componentDidMount() {
  this.loadTime();
  this.loadOtherData();
}
```

but in these two function i am using a setTimeOut() so i can display if i don't do a setTimeOut i'm getting null on the render

```
loadTime() {
  const dateList = [];
  $('.day').each((index, d) => {
   dateList.push(new Date(d.innerText));
   });
const displayImputation = {
  idMantis: $('#mantis').html(),
  dateList: dateList,
  userId: 1
};

this.props.store.loadImputation(displayImputation);

setTimeout(() => {
  const response = this.props.store.privateImputationData;
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i += 1) {
    const stampToDate = response[i].cra.date;

    const o = moment(stampToDate).day();
    for (let x = 0; x < $('.App input').length; x += 1) {
      if (x === o) {
        const input = $('.App input')[x - 1];
        input.value = response[i].temps;
      }
    }
  }
}, 500);  }
```

is it a good practice or is there another solution ?

Comment: Using jQuery in react is bad practice sure. Read about how to process inputs in [official react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: I stopped reading after about 3 lines of your code. Using jQuery for modifying your DOM is going to be problematic with React. Using jQuery for stuff like css animations or pulling data from the DOM is fine, but modifying the DOM is a big no-no.

Comment: it's just a proof of concept i'm not using it, and for the setTimeout() can you help ?

Comment: @Chris in my opinion jquery should never be used. There is everything that can be developed in plain native javascript. Also, jquery adds file size to the react bundle